# How can i use potrait mode in video.js react library

Tags: reactjs, video.js

I want to use potrait mode in video.js library in react

How can i specifically use potrait mode in video.js react
I want to use Potrait Mode and Landscape mode in Video.js react but i got nothing from their documentation and nothing helped me
How can i specifically use potrait mode in video.js react
I want to use Potrait Mode and Landscape mode in Video.js react but i got nothing from their documentation and nothing helped me
How can i specifically use potrait mode in video.js react
I want to use Potrait Mode and Landscape mode in Video.js react but i got nothing from their documentation and nothing helped me

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.